# model instances created with factory_girl have attributes change between build and create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, factory-bot

I'm using `factory_girl` in my rspec tests. I'm having a problem where the `creator_id` is set correctly in the build, then changes to the id of a model created in the previous test. A model with an id from the previous test obviously does not exist, so the test fails. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Part of my `User` factory:

```
factory :unconfirmed_user, class: User do
    sequence(:user_name) { |n| "user#{n}" }
    sequence(:email) { |n| "user#{n}@example.com" }
    sequence(:authentication_token) { |n| "some random token #{n}" }
    sequence(:password) { |n| "password #{n}" }

    roles_mask { 2 } # user role

    trait :confirmed do
      after(:create) do |user|
        user.skip_confirmation_notification!
        #user.confirm!
        user.skip_confirmation!

        user.confirmation_token = user.class.confirmation_token
        user.confirmation_sent_at = Time.now.utc
        user.save(:validate => false)

        user.ensure_authentication_token!
      end
    end
    ....
    factory :confirmed_user, traits: [:confirmed], aliases: [:user, :creator, :updater, :deleter]
    ....
end
```

The logging is done like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  after(:build) { |object|
    is_blank = object.respond_to?(:creator) && object.creator.blank? && !object.is_a?(User)
    Rails.logger.warn "Built #{is_blank ? '[blank]' : ''} [#{object.object_id}] #{object.inspect}"
  }
  after(:create) { |object|
    is_blank = object.respond_to?(:creator) && object.creator.blank? && !object.is_a?(User)
    Rails.logger.warn "Created #{is_blank ? '[blank]' : ''} [#{object.object_id}] #{object.inspect}"
  }

....
```

This is what gets logged. `Project` is a model that has an attribute `creator_id` which is a `User`:

```
Built  [82788672] #<Project id: nil, name: "project14", description: "project description 14", urn: "urn:project:14", notes: "note number 14", creator_id: 100, updater_id: nil, deleter_id: nil, deleted_at: nil, image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
Created [blank] [82788672] #<Project id: 11, name: "project14", description: "project description 14", urn: "urn:project:14", notes: "note number 14", creator_id: 99, updater_id: 99, deleter_id: nil, deleted_at: nil, image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil, created_at: "2014-05-21 04:08:30", updated_at: "2014-05-21 04:08:30">
```

Notice the `creator_id` starts as `100` in `build`, then changes to `99` in `created`. Why is this happening?

**Update**

The relevant parts from the `User` model:

```
require 'role_model'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :token_authenticatable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable

  include RoleModel

  attr_accessible :user_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me,
                  :roles, :roles_mask, :preferences,
                  :image

  roles :admin, :user, :harvester 

  model_stamper

  # relations
  has_many :accessible_projects, through: :permissions, source: :project
  has_many :readable_projects, through: :permissions, source: :project, conditions: 'permissions.level = reader'
  has_many :writable_projects, through: :permissions, source: :project, conditions: 'permissions.level = writer'

  has_many :created_projects, class_name: 'Project', foreign_key: :creator_id, inverse_of: :creator
  has_many :updated_projects, class_name: 'Project', foreign_key: :updater_id, inverse_of: :updater
  has_many :deleted_projects, class_name: 'Project', foreign_key: :deleter_id, inverse_of: :deleter

  # validations
  validates :user_name, presence: true, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :roles_mask, presence: true
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /^image\/(jpg|jpeg|pjpeg|png|x-png|gif)$/, message: 'file type %{value} is not allowed (only jpeg/png/gif images)'

  before_validation :ensure_user_role

  def projects
    (self.created_projects + self.accessible_projects).uniq
  end

  private
  def ensure_user_role
    self.roles << :user if roles_mask.blank?
  end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, including more information (e.g. rspec test, models, etc) would make this a rather complex post. I think I'm in need of a seasoned factory_girl dev or something similar. That said, if there's a piece of information that would make this much clearer, please let me know.

Comment: Since this happens when creating a `User`, I think the problem is in your `User` model, and triggered by one of the calls to the model in `after(:create)`. Please post your `User` code, or if it's a large amount of code, just the relevant parts of it.

Comment: OK, I've added the parts of the User model that I think might be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured this out. The key piece of the puzzle is "After filters are not called when an exception occurs" (found in a comment on the Rails APIDock pages, can't find an exact link at the moment).

The [`userstamp` gem I am using sets the user on a before_filter, then removes the user in an after_filter](https://github.com/theepan/userstamp/blob/bf05d832ee27a717ea9455d685c83ae2cfb80310/lib/userstamp.rb#L8). The problem is that if there is an exception, the after_filter will not run. This does not matter in normal operation - the user will still be set, but will be overwritten when another user logs in. It might cause other security issues I'm not aware of.

The problem in tests is that because the models are created and inserted into the db outside of the usual rails application cycle, the ids stored by the userstamp gem if an exception occurs are maintained between tests (as they're stored in the thread). This means that the wrong user id is stamped (which is why the id changes between build and create).

All up, the rails before_filter and after_filter do not work the same way, leading to confusion. Tests cause different activity in the gem, in this case resulting in state being kept between tests.

I seem to have resolved it by adding calls to reset/clear the stored user at the end of the methods that deal with errors (in my case, in `application_controller.rb`). This ensures that at the end of the action, it is as if the after_filter ran, so the state of the `userstamp` gem is as it expects. I probably need to use a different (and more actively maintained) gem, or fork of that gem :/

Whew.

Comment: I had the same problem with cucumber. So I created a before step hook


     Before do |scenario|
       User.reset_stamper
      end